# printing list of categories as a column

Tags: python, list, pandas, categories, series

I am taking example from pandas documentation. Let us say I have a series after reading an excel file

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["a","b","c","a"], dtype="category")
```

I know I can get different categories by

```
scat=s.cat.categories
print scat
```

For which I get

```
Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')
```

I was wondering what is a good way to make this list appear as a column. Something like

```
a
b
c
```

I could get rid of `u'` by doing `np.asarray` but still do not get the format I need.

Comment: Are you using python 2.x? For python `3.4.3` I've got results without `u`.

Comment: Yes I am using python 2. Interesting that u' does not come in python 3x.

Comment: Could you check `type` of your 'strings'? like `type(scat[0])

Comment: I get str when I do that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure by what you mean when you say 'appear' as a column.

You can create a list instead of an index via:

```
>>> s.cat.categories.tolist()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Or you can simply print them out in a column structure using a for loop:

```
for c in s.cat.categories:
    print c

a
b
c
```

Or you could create a series (or dataframe):

```
>>> pd.Series(s.cat.categories)
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object

>>> pd.DataFrame(s.cat.categories)
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for and that is what I meant as 'appear' as column.  Not that it occurred to me to use a loop but I was thinking there might be a simpler way to achieve it without a loop

Comment: perfect. Series and DataFrames solutions are great ! Nice to learn.

Comment: The output format changes when I use pd.DataFrame(scat) vs print pd.DataFrame(scat). Basically print command removes the nice table in which the output is wrapped. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 5):

I think it is no problem - `'u'` means `unicode` string:

```
s = pd.Series(["a","b","c","a"], dtype="category")
print s
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]

scat=s.cat.categories
print scat
Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')

print scat[0]
a

print type(scat[0])
<type 'str'>
```

If you want print column without loop use [`numpy reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
print len(scat)
3
print scat.values.reshape(len(scat),1)
[['a']
 ['b']
 ['c']]
```

Comment: This is giving me entire data frame. What I need is only unique categories printed. So a should appear only once.